# I cant put canvas into divs without changing the orientation

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is that i want the arrows go row and column but only its only on column

html

```
<div class="grafica" id="grafica">
    <div id="x"></div>
    <div id="y"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.grafica{
     width: 90%;
     height: 95vh;
     box-shadow: 7px 10px 30px -1px black;
}
```

Each arrow its inside of a div, if i dont put the arrows inside the div it work well but i need to do it

javascript

```
function createArrow(){
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;
    canvas.className = 'arrow';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(20, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(10, 20);
    ctx.stroke();

    

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=> {
        let distanceX = getDistanceBetweenElements(canvas, x);
        let distanceY = getDistanceBetweenElements(canvas, y);
        
        let f1 = (k*q1*q2)/distanceX;
        let f2 = (k*q1*q2)/distanceY;

        console.log(f1, f2);
        


        //canvas.style.transform = `rotate(${a}deg)`;
    });
    

    grafica.append(div);
    div.append(canvas);
    
}
```

[image: Bad image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following code to your css:

```
.grafica > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Please check my solution and let me know your feedback.